# polynomial linked list with two structs and its problems

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Term;
struct Node;

typedef Term* termPtr;
typedef Node* list;

list cons(int degree,int coeff, list p);

struct Term
{
    int degree;
    int coeff;
};

struct Node
{
    termPtr term;
    list link;
};
class polynomial
{
private:
    list poly;
static const int VARIABLE_X='X';
char variable;
public:
    polynomial():poly(NULL),variable(VARIABLE_X){};
    polynomial(int coef,int deg);
    polynomial insert (termPtr t,list p);
    int degree() const;
    int coeff(int n) const;
    void setPrintVariable (char x){variable=x;}
    char getPrintVariable()const { return variable;}
    friend const polynomial readPoly();
    friend void printPoly(polynomial a);
    void deletePoly();
    friend const polynomial operator +(const polynomial &a,const polynomial &b);
    friend const polynomial operator *(const polynomial &a,const polynomial &b);
 };

 polynomial::polynomial(int c,int d)
 {
if(poly == NULL)//compiler doesnt understand this part
    poly = cons(c,d,poly);
    else // i put my cons here just to make the poly
            poly=cons(c,d,poly);

}
list cons(int c,int d, list p)
{
    termPtr aterm = new Term;
    aterm->coeff=c;
    aterm->degree=d;
    list q = new Node;
    q->term = aterm;
    q->link = p;
    return q;
} 

void printPoly (polynomial a)
{
cout<<"[";
if(a.poly == NULL)
    cout<<"]";
else
    while(a.poly != NULL)
    {
        cout<<"("<<a.poly->term->coeff<<" X "<<a.poly->term->degree;
        a.poly=a.poly->link ; 
    }
cout<<endl;
}
```

This code is using linked lists to store polynomials.
One struct is for the polynomial degree and coeff; another struct is for making a Node in order to create a linked list.

I have two problems with the code:

1. An empty polynomial which is NULL but in the constructor my condition statement doesn't find it out.
2. Why my print method doesn't work.

I have this problem in the print method

> Unhandled exception at 0x00c1166b in polynomial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "compiler doesn't understand that poly is NULL"? What is the compiler doing and why do you believe it to be wrong? 2. In what way does your print method not work? What does it do? What did you hope it would do instead?

Comment: while I debug it, the condition in the construction ( if (poly==NULL)) is ignored

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "is ignored"? How do you know it's being ignored? 2. Speaking of ignoring things, you ignored my second question.

Comment: In the two-argument `polynomial` constructor, what do you think the value of `poly` should be on entry? Why?

Comment: sorry. I didnt see it. 
first- I meant my poly is empty but it seems it is not null. what condition statement should I use to find out if it is NULL.
second - 
I have this error while I want to print the poly:

Unhandled exception at 0x00c1166b in polynomial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan
 for default constructor the value of poly would be NULL and for the second one which has to int values , the constructor should make a new Node and add it to poly then poly could be a NULL linked list or not NULL one

Comment: As you'll have gathered from Potatoswatter's answer, that constructor actually sees an uninitialized `poly`, which is what I was hoping to nudge you towards noticing :-).

Comment: Incidentally, you have another problem completely unrelated to the ones you've mentioned here. Take a close look at how you're iterating over the list in `printPoly`. What will happen if you call `printPoly` twice on the same polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `poly == NULL` is not `true` is that `poly` is uninitialized. The initialization `poly(NULL)` only occurs in the other constructor, which is not used.

Probably it is best to eliminate the `list` type in favor of `std::list` (actually, it is a very bad idea to use `list` as an identifier in conjunction with `using namespace std;`).

```
class polynomial
{
private:
    list< Term > poly;
```

Now `poly` is default-constructed so `poly->empty()` is `true`, and you don't have to do anything.

For `cons` you can call `list::push_back` or `list::insert`; general catenation of lists is `list::splice`. To iterate over the list use the `++` operator on an object of type `list< Term >::iterator`.

Comment: @Ben: Lol, you're being good to me today. I thought about suggesting `std::` but bias towards avoiding messing with their style…

Comment: I was more concerned about "list of what" than use of a qualified name.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't have caught that one. Well… for someone who isn't yet familiar with which names are used by the library, it might be good to start off using `std::` and not `using`.

Comment: I initialized poly and some of my problem get solved.
your rest is very advanced to me. sorry I couldn't get them. my bad